# Android FAB transform to menu

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, material-design, floating-action-button

As per the updated material guidelines, the floating action button can transform into a menu as shown below:

[image: Fab to menu]

Can someone help me with some code or a some links on how to implement this behavior?

Thank you.

Comment: Look at this: https://github.com/zendesk/android-floating-action-button

Comment: Not all material components are implemented yet. The FAB menu and the FAB speed dial remain unimplemented and looking at the issue tracker, there seems to be no plan on implementing them soon. As @GiuseppeCriscione I suggest you look into a third party library.

Comment: @geek919 i added a background color instead of transparent

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this way

add below `dependencies`

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha05'
```

**Layout file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/sheet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/fab_transformation_sheet_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#2196F3"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="ASK Nilesh" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#FF9800"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="ASK Nilesh" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#9C27B0"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="ASK Nilesh" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvClose"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="2dp"
                android:background="#9C27B0"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:text="Close" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fabMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" />
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Activity Code**

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        fabMenu.setOnClickListener {
            fabMenu.setExpanded(true)
        }
        tvClose.setOnClickListener {
            fabMenu.setExpanded(false)
        }
    }
}
```

You can find complete example here https://github.com/askNilesh/floating_action_button_menu
**OUTPUT**

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks mate

Comment: FabTransformationSheetBehavior is deprecated - any standard solution?

Comment: @HariShankarS are you sure? please check the documentation of FabTransformationSheetBehavior https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/transformation/FabTransformationSheetBehavior

Comment: That component is deprecated. We should be using MaterialContainerTransform instead.